# How to add "Continued" to the title of references?

Tags: natbib

I am writing my thesis and have some difficulty in modifying the title of the references.

I am using a special class ([PhDthesisPSnPDF](http://web.mit.edu/carrien/Public/latex/phd/PhDtemplateLATEX/Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls)) but it uses the class "book".

I use natbib and have a bibliography which spans over 4 pages. I want to have a title over the last three pages saying "References (Continued)".

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) would it be acceptable to have this title in the running head?

Comment: Thanks!, yeap no need to be title at all just "References (Continued)" at the very top of the last three pages in references.

Comment: in that case, try `\markboth{References (Continued)}{References (Continued)}` just before the first entry in the bibliography.  you may have to go into the `.bbl` file to do it; that would get wiped out if you have to reprocess from  a `.bib` file, but it should do the job.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you for your answer, indeed that worked. What if i want it as a title floating on the following reference pages, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first page of the references chapter is usually set in page style plain, therefore the new headers can already be set at the start of the bibliography. Simplified example (the class `PhDthesisPSnPDF` is based on `report`) with the bibliography given explicitely,
it should also work with using the `.bbl` file.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}%
\pagestyle{headings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ORG@thebibliography}{}
\let\ORG@thebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand*{\thebibliography}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % without uppercasing
%  \markboth{References (Continued)}{References (Continued)}%
  % with uppercasing
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{References (Continued)}}%
           {\MakeUppercase{References (Continued)}}%
  % disable the header setting of the original thebibliography
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \ORG@thebibliography
}
% Clear the header after the last page of the bibliography
\let\ORG@endthebibliography\endthebibliography
\def\endthebibliography{%
  \clearpage
  \markboth{}{}%
  \csname ORG@endthebibliography\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{2010} First.

\newpage
\bibitem{2011} Second.
\newpage

\bibitem{2012} Third.

\end{thebibliography}
\cleardoublepage
After references.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]